# distribute AIR application attached with MYSql database

Tags: mysql, actionscript-3, sqlite, mongodb, air

How can i distibute an AIR application attached with MySQL database. I actually want, that the user should not be bothered with setting up the database ( the way it needs to be done, when installing a web application like wordpress etc, that communicates with database).
Also cannot use JSON or XML, as the data is confidential.

Can sqlite or mongo be a better option ?

Vishwas

Comment: You can use local SQLite database, Air supports encryption with it, http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/encrypted_database.html

Comment: You can't embed a MongoDB instance. And even if you could technically, the license probably may not be a good match for your application (AGPL).

Comment: Storing something as JSON or XML is no less (or more) secure than putting it in a DB. If you want data to be secure, then encrypt it. Where you store it is a different issue.